# How to send mail for multiple models in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to rails. I am having problem in mail sending to multiple models. Our project contains parent,teacher and student models.each module having number of users(student,parent,teacher).  And also I am having three check box.that is student,teacher,parent.when I click student and teacher.the mail should be sent to all teachers and all students.

If I want send  a mail to teacher and also student means ,the problem behind this, mail was sending only to teacher not student. how to solve this problem.and I included my coding.

Controller

```
def send_news_letter  

     if params[:announcement].present?
        @announcement = Announcement.find(params[:announcement].keys).first
      end
    if params[:students].present? and params[:teachers].present?
        @student = Student.pluck(:email)
        @teacher = Teacher.pluck(:email)
        UserMailer.send_multiple_email(@student,@teacher,@announcement).deliver
        redirect_to announcements_url, :notice => "Newsletter Delivered Successfully" a
      end
```

end

Usermailer.rb

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default to: Proc.new {Teacher.pluck(:email)},
          to: Proc.new {Student.pluck(:email)}, 
          from: "from@example.com"


  # Subject can be set in your I18n file at config/locales/en.yml
  # with the following lookup:
  #
  #   en.user_mailer.password_reset.subject
  #
  def password_reset(user)
   @user = user
   mail :to => user.email, :subject => "Password Reset"
  end

  def send_multiple_email(user,employee,announcement)
   @user = user
   @employee = employee
   @announcement = announcement
   mail :subject => "Deliver"
   end


end
```

Please help me.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, in your controller I would store all addresses in one array:

```
@emails = []
if params[:students].present?
  @emails += Student.pluck(:email)
end
if params[:teachers].present?
  @emails += Teacher.pluck(:email)
end
if params[:parents].present?
  @emails += Parent.pluck(:email)
end

UserMailer.send_multiple_email(@emails,@announcement).deliver
```

And then in your mailer change to this:

```
def send_multiple_email(emails,announcement)
  @announcement = announcement
  emails.each do | address |
    mail :to => address, :subject => "Deliver"
  end
end
```

Please note, that if you're referencing your models in the mailer template (such as "Hi `<%= @user.name %>`!") then you need to load the whole model object. Now you're just using pluck to get a list of all the addresses you want to send to. To get the whole model, change `pluck(:email)` to `all` in your controller and change your mailer to reference the attributes in that model instead. This also means your three models need to have the same attribute names (at least the ones you intend to use in the mailer).

Hope it makes sense.

Comment: The Mail was send only one person.